# Ignoring newlines for better spacing? Or alternative?

Tags: formatting, code

So when I code, say in C++, I like to separate blocks of code with spacing, etc. This makes it easier to navigate and interpret. When I separate out a block, it becomes clear that that is a unit that serves some particular purpose.

In Latex, I do this for navigation reasons and clarity. However this causes undesired consequences: New paragraphs when I don't want them. For example, I like to write proofs as follows:

```
\begin{proof}
etc. etc. etc.
(blank line)
\end{proof}
```

This way it's easy to see where the end of a long proof is. However, this causes the QED symbol to be on a new line: Not ideal.

Also, I like to separate an eqnarray environment with new lines too.

Is there any way to attain better clarify with space? Or is this something I should just live without?

Comment: Don't use `eqnarray` environments any more. There are better alternatives.

Comment: Putting `%(blank line)` in place of your `(blank line)` should give a visible end of theorem without beginning a new paragraph.

Comment: `\endlinechar=-1`

Comment: Alternatively, ``\catcode`\^^M=13 \let^^M=\space``

Comment: C++ is a very different animal, the main purpose of TeX is *typesetting text* and blank lines are obviously significant. The `\end{proof}` line already is the marker.

Comment: That's kind of the point of my question: That blank lines have a meaning in Latex, which disallows spacing for clarity. The commenting of new lines is a great solution though.